# how to disable Internet Explorer 10 Password Eye using windows 7

Tags: operating-systems

The instructions for Windows 8 does not work for Windows 7.  How do I remove the Password Eye from Windows 7.  Thank you.

Comment: I tried the instructions on my Windows 7 virtual machine and they worked without a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

1. Click Start, run, and then type **regedit** into the box
2. Go to HLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
3. If it does not exists, create ot
4. Add a DWORD key with the name 'DisablePasswordReveal' and the value '0x00000001'

Comment: Why provide the exact same answer somebody else has provided?  Compared to the duplicate question' answer which says EXACTLY the samething with screenshots, I don't find this answer helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the duplicate till after I posted.